# Discrete mathematics - Set Theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let d ∈ N be a given natural number. Let E ⊆ N be any subset of the natural numbers which has the following properties:

(i) 0 ∈ E ;
(ii) d ∈ E ;
(iii) for any x,y ∈ E, one has x+y ∈ E.

Let D ⊆ N denote the subset N consisting of all multiples of d ; thus

D := { n ∈ N : there exists l ∈ N such that n=d.l}.

Show that D ⊆ E.

I am totally stuck at this questions, can anyone help?

Comment: Hint. Prove by induction on $l$ that $dl \in E$.

Answer (score 0):

We argue by contradiction. Suppose instead that $D \setminus E \neq \emptyset$. Then since $D \setminus E \subseteq \mathbb N$, it follows by the Well-Ordering Principle that it has a least element, say $k \in D \setminus E$. Now since $k \in D$, we know that $k = d\ell$ for some $\ell \in \mathbb N$. But since $k \notin E$ and [by properties (ii) and (iii)] $0 \in E$ and $d \in E$, notice that $\ell \geq 2$.

Now consider $d(\ell - 1)$. Since $\ell - 1 \geq 1$ and $\ell \in \mathbb N$, we know that $\ell - 1 \in \mathbb N$ so that $d(\ell - 1) \in D$. But since $d(\ell - 1) < d\ell = k$ and $k$ is the **least** element in $D \setminus E$, it follows that $d(\ell - 1) \notin D \setminus E$ so that $d(\ell - 1) \notin D$ or $d(\ell - 1) \in E$. But since we just showed that $d(\ell - 1) \in D$, we know that $d(\ell - 1) \in E$. Thus, since [by property (ii)] $d \in E$, it follows by property (iii) that $d(\ell - 1) + d = d\ell = k \in E$, contradicting the fact that $k \notin E$. So we conclude that $D \subseteq E$, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$